# curl doesn't get site contents on PHP via HTTPS

Tags: php, unix, curl

I have read all the internet and tried almost all solutions, nothing works.

If I run curl http://... site, it works but if i run https://... it doesn't.

I' running centos 7 with php 5.6

Nothing happens also if I try the famous answer with

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

The only thing that can help me getting the site is

```
curl -4svo/dev/null --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha https://.....
```

however since i need to send my headers, it is not a solution, i need something compatible with the curl_setopt.

**UPDATE ERROR**

> I get this: curl: (35) Cannot communicate securely with peer: no
>   common encryption algorithm(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the magic line!

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha');`

Answer (score 1):

i think , this problem is caused by the version of cURL not supporting ECC 256 bit SSL certificates and the ECDSA signature algorithm (which is used by CloudFlare). You can test to see if your version of cURL supports this encryption by running:

```
curl -1IsS --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha https://sslspdy.com
```

If you get the following, then your cURL is out of date:

```
curl: (59) Unknown cipher in list: ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_128_sha
```

Comment: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Wed, 28 Oct 2015 10:42:24 GMT

Comment: Im already banging my head to the walls with this curl thing for the last 12h

Comment: try this:curl --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha https://repo.thinkofdeath.co.uk/content/groups/public/

Comment: returns empty: [root@centos7 bf]# curl --ciphers ecdhe_ecdsa_aes_256_sha repo.thinkofdeath.co.uk/content/groups/public
[root@centos7 bf]#